# Distance between two ellipsoids via Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, ellipsoids

I want to use Lagrange multipliers to find the minimum separating distance between two ellipsoids, both centered at the origin.

To illustrate, we start with both ellipsoids sharing the same center:

[image]

And want to finish with the closest point that the two ellipsoids may be separated:

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by separating distance?

Comment: $X^TAX=1$ is an ellipsoid centered at the origin. Once you move it, it becomes $(X-X_0)^TA(X-X_0)=1$

Comment: @Chrystomath: Thanks, edited.

Comment: Why is $X$ outside the surface of the ellipsoid defined by $B$?

Comment: Good point. The solution should satisfy being on the surfaces of both ellipsoids, but the position of the centre of the displaced ellipsoid A, C,  relative to the stationary ellipsoid, B, should be outside. i.e. the ellipsoids must touch and not be inside one another.

Comment: Got it, every point of $B$ should be outside of $A$. Maybe you should simply solve the problem with $X$ satisfying both surface equations, and discard the solutions you don't want.

Comment: Note: you want to set the partial derivatives of the Lagrangian to 0, not minimize them ;)

Comment: Thought: you may want to add a condition on the dot product (has to be negative) of the normals of the surfaces at $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- We want to minimize the distance between two ellipsoids, defined $(X-C)^{T}A(X-C)$ and $X^{T}BX^{T}$.
- This means we want to minimize the squared displacement of $C$, $|C|^{2}$ under certain conditions:

1. $X$ is on the surface of the ellipsoid defined by $A$, i.e $(X-C)^{T}A(X-C) - 1 = 0$
2. $X$ is on the surface of the ellipsoid defined by $B$, i.e $(X)^{T}B(X) - 1 = 0$
3. According to [this paper][3], the gradients of the two points at the point of contact should be equal and of opposite sign.

We therefore let

$2A(X-C) = -2s^{2}BX$

where $s^2$ is some positive scalar to be minimized.

Rearranging, we get:
$(X-C) = -s^{2}A^{-1}BX$

Substituting $X = rV$, where $r$ is a distance absorbed into $s^{2}$  and $V$ is a unit vector:

Let $X-C = -s^{2} \alpha V$, such that $(X-C) = s^{2}(I - \alpha)V = s^{2}\beta V$

This yields the additional constraint:

$V^{T}V - 1 = 0$

Using the above, we may build the Lagrangian Multiplier:

$\mathcal{L} = s^{4}V^{T} \beta^{T} \beta V 
- \lambda_{0}s^{4}(V^{T} \alpha^{T} A \alpha V - 1) 
- \lambda_{1}s^{4}(V^{T}BV - 1) 
- \lambda_{2}(V^{T}V - 1)$

From this we derive a set of 5 differential equations to solve:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial s} = 4s^{3}V^{T}(\beta^{T}\beta - \lambda_{0}\alpha^{T}A\alpha - \lambda_{1}B)V$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial V} = 2s^{4}(\beta^{T}\beta - \lambda_{0}\alpha^{T}A\alpha - \lambda_{1}B - \lambda_{2}s^{-4}I)V$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_{0}} = -s^{4}(V^{T} \alpha^{T} A \alpha V - 1)$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_{1}} = -s^{4}(V^{T} B V - 1)$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_{2}} = -(V^{T}V - 1)$

Solving numerically gives a nice result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given symmetric and positive definite matrices $\rm A$ and $\rm B$ and vector $c$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm x - \mathrm y \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & (\mathrm x - \mathrm c)^\top \mathrm A \, (\mathrm x - \mathrm c) = 1\\ & \mathrm y^\top \mathrm B \, \mathrm y = 1\end{array}$$

---

[optimization](/questions/tagged/optimization) [qcqp](/questions/tagged/qcqp) [lagrange-multiplier](/questions/tagged/lagrange-multiplier)

Comment: I have already tried this solution and it does not appear to work, on the condition that c = 0.